# why is it recommended using design pattern in a web or app project?

Tags: design-patterns

why is it recommended using design pattern in a web or app project ?
i only use only MVC.

it depends of type project for using a design pattern? or it depends of Project team?

Sorry for the novice question

Comment: Design Patterns are known and repeatable designs for solving specific problems. In the case of MVC, that is a common design pattern for solving the specific problem of writing a GUI application. The fact that it is for a web or desktop or phone application is immaterial to the core ideas of writing a GUI.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i'm using Dango in this moment and i read  this post about MCV in dango -> http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Django/Python_Django_MVC_Model_View_Controller_Framework.php

you have a information about desing pattern for web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all MVC is also a design pattern.
A design pattern is nothing but standard ways of solving common problem. The rationale behind using it is :

1. You avoid the mistakes people make in a new approach.
2. It is a widely acceptable methodology . Hence, fully tested and limitations are known without doing much deep diving.
3. Saves time because of 1st and 2.

There are lot of design pattern. Some applies to low level designing(Singleton pattern, Decorator etc. the list is huge) when you implement or to a class diagram or use case analysis.
Some applies to Design high level architecture of system. By applying the patterns in this case you will achieve scalability , security and other non-functional requirements of your website/app. For example it has become a heavily used approach to horizontally scale the system of cheaper machine and put load balancer.

These two pattern LLD and HLD pattern for project type and requirements.

The other kind of pattern is going for a scrum model which usually depends on the team strategies.